# How to add menu to user's right click tauri rust?

Tags: macos, rust, tauri

I am trying to add a menu option to the user's right-click menu for a mac app using tauri rust. I can't find any docs on this. Is it possible to add an option to the user's right-click? For example, when they select a file, our option should show up, like "Change the wallpaper."

for ex:
[image]

Update:

After some research, I found that this is possible with Finder Sync Extensions, but I have no idea how to integrate it with Rust Tauri.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html

Comment: You need [NSServices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsservices?language=objc), not Finder Sync extensions. I didn't see anything in Tauri that helps with that, however.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any example code? It's okay if it's in Swift; I will try to port it to Rust.

Comment: this looks like a good [primer](http://www.edenwaith.com/blog/index.php?p=133)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a custom menu option to the user's right-click menu on mac isn't currently possible through tauri's core functionalities.

Integrating a Finder sync extension with a Tauri Rust application requires a workaround, but it's possible, as I have done so for a custom option to copy file paths when right-clicking on files(couldn't get it working for folders for some reason)

Here is the method I followed:

1. I created a standalone Mac application that is designed for the Finder Sync extension, and I added the functionality for the custom option.
2. Then create a way for our Tauri application to communicate with the extension, there are a few ways to do this:

- Use `AppleScript` to send data from the extension to our Tauri app.
- A simpler option(what I used): write the data to a location on your filesystem and allow both apps to access it

3. Use `notify` or `tokio` to watch modification to that file.
4. Parse the data, extract and perform the functionality through our Tauri app.

You might have to update your UI accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I am a bit confused. How can I install the .appex file?

Comment: I assume you have built the Finder Sync extension as a .appex file. Make sure the Finder Sync application is properly code signed, (essential to be accepted by macos) you can use XCode or cmd tools by apple.

Comment: Install the extension by copying it to the required location, typically in `~/Library/Services/`, Do:  `cp -R YourFinderSyncExtension.appex ~/Library/Services/`

Comment: You need to then enable the extension in `System Preferences >> Extensions >> Finder`  and then enable the extension(tick).

Comment: Then Relanch finder(Option + Right-click on the Finder icon in the Dock and selecting "Relaunch")